# How to add first name & last name to default registration form?

Tags: functions, user-registration, profiles

is it possible to add first name & last name to the default registration form of wordpress?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add this code in functions.php

```
add_action( 'register_form', 'myplugin_register_form' );
function myplugin_register_form() {

    $first_name = ( ! empty( $_POST['first_name'] ) ) ? trim( $_POST['first_name'] ) : '';
    $last_name = ( ! empty( $_POST['last_name'] ) ) ? trim( $_POST['last_name'] ) : '';

        ?>
        <p>
            <label for="first_name"><?php _e( 'First Name', 'mydomain' ) ?><br />
                <input type="text" name="first_name" id="first_name" class="input" value="<?php echo esc_attr( wp_unslash( $first_name ) ); ?>" size="25" /></label>
        </p>

        <p>
            <label for="last_name"><?php _e( 'Last Name', 'mydomain' ) ?><br />
                <input type="text" name="last_name" id="last_name" class="input" value="<?php echo esc_attr( wp_unslash( $last_name ) ); ?>" size="25" /></label>
        </p>

        <?php
    }

    //2. Add validation. In this case, we make sure first_name and last_name is required.
    add_filter( 'registration_errors', 'myplugin_registration_errors', 10, 3 );
    function myplugin_registration_errors( $errors, $sanitized_user_login, $user_email ) {

        if ( empty( $_POST['first_name'] ) || ! empty( $_POST['first_name'] ) && trim( $_POST['first_name'] ) == '' ) {
            $errors->add( 'first_name_error', __( '<strong>ERROR</strong>: You must include a first name.', 'mydomain' ) );
        }
        if ( empty( $_POST['last_name'] ) || ! empty( $_POST['last_name'] ) && trim( $_POST['last_name'] ) == '' ) {
            $errors->add( 'last_name_error', __( '<strong>ERROR</strong>: You must include a last name.', 'mydomain' ) );
        }
        return $errors;
    }

    //3. Finally, save our extra registration user meta.
    add_action( 'user_register', 'myplugin_user_register' );
    function myplugin_user_register( $user_id ) {
        if ( ! empty( $_POST['first_name'] ) ) {
            update_user_meta( $user_id, 'first_name', trim( $_POST['first_name'] ) );
            update_user_meta( $user_id, 'last_name', trim( $_POST['last_name'] ) );
        }
    }
```

For more info see [codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Customizing_the_Registration_Form)

You can also use some plugins

[cimy-user-extra-fields](https://wordpress.org/plugins/cimy-user-extra-fields/)

[Custom Registration Form](https://wordpress.org/plugins/fma-additional-registration-attributes/)

[User Registration Aide](https://wordpress.org/plugins/user-registration-aide)

Answer (score 0):

The code works, but I've spotted a small bug. On the validation of the last_name, the last var in the if condition hast "first_name", and must have "last_name". So that piece of code, correctly, would be:

```
if ( empty( $_POST['last_name'] ) || ! empty( $_POST['last_name'] ) && trim( $_POST['last_name'] ) == '' ) {
     $errors->add( 'last_name_error', __( '<strong>ERROR</strong>: You must include a first name.', 'mydomain' ) );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$form['account']['lname'] = array('#type' => 'textfield',
'#title' => t('LastName'),
'#default_value' => $edit['LastName'],
'#maxlength' => LASTNAME_MAX_LENGTH,
'#description' => t('Spaces are allowed; punctuation is not allowed except for periods, hyphens, and underscores.'),
'#required' => TRUE,
);
```

you can do it in the UI only

Navigate to the `sitedomain/admin/config/people/accounts/fields` and add the first name, lastname as the fields it will display First name and last name the default registration form